# Clipping the caret

Tags: c++, winapi, caret, clip

I'm writing my own control. It contains the caret. I use the `SetCaretPos()` function to move the caret. And it works well when I move the caret inside the window:

[image]

But when I set a negative y-coordinate for `SetCaretPos()`, the caret is drawn outside the control window:

```
SetCaretPos(10, -5);
```

[image]

Then I used `IntersectClipRect()` function to create new clipping region:

```
RECT rcClip, rcClient;
GetClientRect(hEditWnd_MultyLine, &rcClient);

CopyRect(&rcClip, &rcClient);
rcClip.left += 2;//add left margin
rcClip.right -= 2;//add right margin
rcClip.top += 2;//add top margin
rcClip.bottom -= 2;//add bottom margin

HDC _hdc = GetDC(mywnd_hwnd);
IntersectClipRect(_hdc, rcClip.left, rcClip.top, rcClip.right, rcClip.bottom);
ReleaseDC(mywnd_hwnd, _hdc);
```

And it works fine only for graphics operations like `FillRect()`, but it has no effect on the caret drawing - there is no caret clipping:

[image]

**My question is** - how to clip caret drawing when its y-coordinate is negative?
I need this:

[image]

Comment: The caret is supposed to represent the location of user input. Why would you ever need to let the user enter input outside of your control's bounds? This makes no sense. What is the use case?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will use content scrolling, so the caret may partially move outside the window's client area. The question is how to do it?

Comment: "T'is the way" in Windows. Caret and focus stay where they are whatever user does

Comment: Might be useful somehow: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21437/A-Padded-Rich-Text-Box-Subclass

Comment: when I set a negative y-coordinate for SetCaretPos(), the caret is not drawn outside the control window, but is clipped out. Could you please provide a minimum sample to help us reproduce the issue?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790077/clipping-the-caret-in-a-c-sharp-program

Comment: Just use CreateCaret with computed height. This is what rich text box does, otherwise most controls just don't use viewports non-aligned on line heights (text box does that I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can't do it that simply. Clipping region is part of GDI and caret belongs to the "window" - the native control.

Judging by what WinForms and C# offer, I think there are several ways to do so:

- create a smaller caret, or
- use a sub-control to draw caret, and
- hide and draw own caret in that case.